# combining rows based on a condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filtering, subset

I am trying to remove some useless rows from the below `df`. There can be a `type` (1:5) per ID and `yes_no` variable to see if there is a variable recorded or not. As you can see, I would like to remove the 3rd and 5th rows as they have other rows with the same `ID` and `type` with a recorded value with `yes_no = y`.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), type = c("1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "5"), yes_no = c("n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "y", "n"), value = c(NA, NA, NA, "2", NA, "5", "6", NA))

 ID type yes_no value
  1    1      n  <NA>
  1    2      n  <NA>
  1    3      n  <NA>
  1    3      y     2
  1    4      n  <NA>
  1    4      y     5
  1    4      y     6
  1    5      n  <NA>
```

The desired output is as follows:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), type = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "4", "5"), yes_no = c("n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "n"), value = c(NA, NA, "2", "5", "6", NA))

 ID type yes_no value
  1    1      n  <NA>
  1    2      n  <NA>
  1    3      y     2
  1    4      y     5
  1    4      y     6
  1    5      n  <NA>
```

There are ID's other than 1 that have types 1:5 so looks like I have to `group_by(ID)`. A `dplyr` solution would be great too.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use an `if` condition to check if `yes_no` has `any` `y` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, type) %>%
  filter(if(any(yes_no == 'y')) yes_no == 'y' else TRUE) %>%
  ungroup

#  ID    type  yes_no value
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#1 1     1     n      NA   
#2 1     2     n      NA   
#3 1     3     y      2    
#4 1     4     y      5    
#5 1     4     y      6    
#6 1     5     n      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  df,
  ave(yes_no == "y", ID, type, FUN = max) == (yes_no == "y")
)
```

gives

```
  ID type yes_no value
1  1    1      n  <NA>
2  1    2      n  <NA>
4  1    3      y     2
6  1    4      y     5
7  1    4      y     6
8  1    5      n  <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

After grouping by 'ID', 'type', we may use an OR (`|`) condition to `filter` to filter the groups where 'y' is present or when `all` elements are not 'y'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID, type) %>% 
   filter(yes_no == 'y'|all(yes_no != 'y')) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  ID    type  yes_no value
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1 1     1     n      <NA> 
2 1     2     n      <NA> 
3 1     3     y      2    
4 1     4     y      5    
5 1     4     y      6    
6 1     5     n      <NA>
```